# Async tests stop working in node 10, work in node 12. How to diagnose?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, polyfills, jsdom

The long and the short if it is thus:

1. Large test suite with some async/await tests (e.g. `describe( async function(){const awaitSomething = something (...); expect(awaitSomething).to.equal('somethingAwaited')}` or similar) that runs in node 10.15.3
2. Introduce a colleagues component library (which itself runs with tests in node 10.15 3)
3. Our large test suite fails unless we upgrade to node 12.x

Specifically this causes tests to fail **even when** we specify to `.only` run unrelated test suites. As soon as we comment out the import of the component function where it's integrated and where it's rested all other test failures cease.

We can most likely upgrade to node 12.x, but I would still like to understand what is wrong.

The only two clues are that the new component pulls `whatwg-fetch`, and that in node 10.15.3 we get an error (with or without the component imported) saying

> `ExperimentalWarning: fs.promises is experimental`.

This comes from inside jsdom.

As I can't paste code from the code base, I can't make an MVP to show here, but is there a way to diagnose this? I've tried using `DEBUG='*'` but I can't get anything meaningful out of it. My leading guess is that polyfill is overriding something but I don't know what.

Comment: more likely that something in a dependency from your mate's lib is _not_ fully compatible with Node v10. This warning is saying "I know this instruction, but it's not officially deployed yet". And it's probably from an `import`, so no matter whether you comment some tests. You can avoid it by running Node with the `--experimental-module` flag. For this particular error, the [changelog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/uncategorized/10-lts-to-12-lts/#notable-changes-in-node-js-11-14-0) says it stopped in v11.14.0. No idea how to trace it though.

Comment: @StockOverflaw that would make sense, but it's not clear why it runs for them on Node 10.15.3 though? Also, we are getting that warning with or without the component imported, which makes me wonder if it is a red herring?

Comment: Ah right, I missed that _both_ codebases can run in the same v10... So, maybe npm resolves dependencies differently when run inside your main codebase, or the configuration is different (`--no-warnings` on the component in standalone mode?), or maybe some TypeScript-like transpiling machinery doesn't produce the same results (target ES, version of the transpiler...)? Other than that, search everywhere (even node_modules) for `/(fs|\))\.promises/` to see where it could come from... no other idea! :/

Comment: I've looked at `process.versions` and `process.config` and they're the same with or without the component. I had a look through for references to `fs.promises` once and didn't find anything. The only thing I can think of is that we (main app) mock some stuff for `JSDom` but that shouldn't effect our tests (or should it?)

Comment: That's why I suggested a regex: chances are, the guilty line is `require('fs').promises`. Mocking stuff should be affecting the main code as well I suppose. I also doubt you code pure JS from the start, that's why the issue could be lying in the "compiled" version, which may have different versions/configurations/targets if each project.

Comment: @StockOverflaw I looked with regex and I found some stuff, but I have no idea if it's causing the issues or not. It's all in the UMD versions of the component, which we don't use and their package.json doesn't reference...

Comment: It just means it's dependencies of dependencies, but these pieces of code are surely executed. Not much more I can do to help here though, but if you find why there's this discrepancy between the 2 projects for the same Node version, it would be interesting: clearly this is some serious mystery...